# Looking for a Wordpress template to integrate CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, templates, integration

We have some issues about wordpress themes we bought at theme forest and CiviCRM.
When i google I find a a lot of same problems other users have with the CiviCRM backend and some wordpress themes.
Before I buy any new one I really wanna be sure that there are no problems with CiviCRM.
Is there any list of compatible wordpress themes somewhere here?
Or what kind of creative themes do you guys use together with CiviCRM?
Thanks for any suggestions and help.

Comment: It might help to tell us what the issues were: ie. civi not running because the theme had some conflicting code, or visual issues where the css was hiding parts of Civi or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the latest and greatest Civi and Wordpress - most themes should work fine.

There was an issue with backbone conflicts that may have caused issues with some themes- but that was addressed in 4.7.31. Outside of that - I never had an issue with the CiviCRM backend when using any front end theme. However, I have had conflicting CSS on the front end that can typically be fixed by changing some lines in your CSS.

As for what theme I use - a modified version of twentyseventeen.

Comment: My experience with CiviCRM and WordPress is you need to manually go over each front-end page and restyle it to match your style guide. A pain but easier than turning off all of civi's css.